# Z-index troubles with nivo slider and dropdown menu

Tags: css

I thought the answer to this would be relatively straight forward but have thus far not been able to get it working for me.

Basically at this url I have a slider which keeps sitting above a drop down menu which drops down from lingerie link.

http://cocoslingerie.co.uk/

I have set the drop down to a higher z-index than the nivo slider but still no luck.

Can anybody make any suggestions?

Comment: Please add meaningful code to your question. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem will help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: I agree, but in this case I am not sure an example other than what is in the page would really hold much value.

Comment: Normally I'd agree with jdwire but in this case I'll make an exception :P

Answer (score 5):

@mgrahamjo answer is correct, just thought I'd add another interesting way to solve this problem

```
.slider-wrapper{
  opacity: 0.99;
}
```

which exploits the quirky nature of z-index, opacity and stacking.  More in depth explanation here:

http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Comment: Bravo for the solution and the link that explain

Comment: Was trying to figure this problem out for days. Thank you so much. Worked perfectly. Just changed the class name to the id of my outermost slider element. #slider

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the position and z-index of the outermost wrapper of the slider:

```
#slide .slider {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
}
```